# Meaning of chemical potential in chemical reactions

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, chemical-potential

In my thermodynamics course, we introduced the chemical potential as a modification of the first + second law of thermodynamics in the case of a system that can exchange particles with its surroundings (consider only PV work):

\begin{equation}
dU = TdS - pdV + \sum_{j=1}\mu_j dN_j
\end{equation}
where the sum is over all the components of the system. This makes sense to me - even if we keep everything else constant, just by adding more matter to the system the energy should increase. Now, this should be true for a closed system undergoing a chemical reaction, so the 3rd term on the RHS could be non-zero. If we consider a quasistatic process, we can identify the first and second terms on the RHS as the heat and work. So the chemical potential term appears to represent some sort of energy transfer separate from heat and work, but how is this possible? Aren't heat and work the only ways to transfer energy?

And if the chemical potential term represents some sort of work in this case, how come the term which we defined to just explain the increase of the internal energy with the increase of the amount of matter in the system also coincidentally can now be interpreted as a work term?

In other words, my question is how do I physically interpret the chemical potential term?

I asked this question in Physics Stack Exchange (I am a physics student), but I wasn't able to obtain an answer that made complete sense to me (I was told that internal energy doesn't include bond energy, but I couldn't find a source that confirms this).

Comment: The chemical potential is just as you state: it's the response of the energy of the system to a change in the number of particles. Its use and interpretation are pretty broad: It can be used to determine the gradient of density due to pressure or acceleration. Also the derivation of freezing and boiling point suppression and elevation use the chemical potential. In chemical equilibrium, the mixing entropy of the reactants and products equals the chemical potential of the system. Probably the best way to get aquatinted with it is to do some exercises which involve the chemical potential.

Comment: @Peter - Cross-posting is frowned upon here, we are happy to have the question on chem.SE as long as you remove it from physics.SE.

Comment: I am afraid that saying that the only way to transfer energy is heat or work is too much confined in the mechanics realm

Comment: @Alchimista But doesn't that contradict the first law of thermodynamics?

Comment: @Peter I see what you mean. But I didn't want to say that it's not. Actually I sent the comment before finishing and I am still thinking of it ;)

Comment: @Peter I am not much versed on formalism but in the first principle it seems we forget to say "at fixed composition". This is at the eye of mine as a chemist is very much clear, as for different chemical species must have different internal energy whatever sum of energies this latter is (here i must mention that U does include bond energy, opposite to what you have been told at Physics SE. Change in this latter component are what are affected by reactions) "Aren't heat and work the only way to transfer energy?" Yes and not, a substance carries its own internal energy.

Comment: Isn't pdV a specific type of work? If energy is capacity to do work, as the chemical environment of atoms changes so does their energy. Atkins ch. 15-17 is a great source on this topic.